# How to get the neighbouring boroughs from a UK postcode?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I need to do an API lookup to get the neighbouring borough information from a UK postcode.

So if the user put in NW1:

> -- Camden (user borough)

I would like to retrieve the associated neighbours:

1. -- Islington
2. -- City of Westminster
3. -- Brent
4. -- Barnet

I have tried looking at geocode from Google Maps

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NW1&key=AIzaSyAU7FVMQGSbAGO0aXHJ1hXi0N0BbkQpvhU

Here is a JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cfrapLma/36/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var apikey = "AIzaSyAU7FVMQGSbAGO0aXHJ1hXi0N0BbkQpvhU";      
      var postcode = "NW1"; 

      var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+postcode+"&key="+apikey; 

      $.getJSON( url, function( data ) { 
        console.log(data);
      });
});
```

Comment: Why is the post given a -3 -- its not a simple straightforward task from what I've read -- I can get the lat, lng -- but it doesn't show the borough.. It also doesn't show neighbouring bouroughs -- so ask me a question here - if you think I've done sufficient research - help point me in the right direction

Comment: Ok well - please provide a method of getting a neighbouring bourough using google maps -- if everyone assumes its straightforward and just wants to de-mark this urgent urgent requirement

Comment: I think the original question wasn't very clear, I have amended it a bit to show the first part of the question is what you want, not what you are getting (feel free to edit again if I did not understand it). However, would you clarify what you get back from the API call? What is it not doing that you need?

Comment: The Google Maps API doesn't provide this function. Try geonames.org.

Comment: Thank you -- can geonames find neighbouring bouroughs? -- is the api free? etc..

Comment: Also, in relation to marking questions as urgent, please don't do this - [see this community discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). Thanks.

Comment: "get the neighbouring borough information from a UK postcode" -- the data coming back from the geocode gmap call does not contain bourough details for itself - or neighbouring boroughs

Comment: -- the geonames solution has been rejected --  "the answer it provided is too granular"

Comment: You could look at [free material from Ordnance Survey](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/finder.html?Licensed%20for=OpenData%20(Free)&withdrawn=on) - they have APIs and postcode datasets. The postcode data is excellent, but you will probably need to convert it from E/N to lat/long, and import all 1.7M rows, so it is not trivial to handle.

Comment: -- @halfer it may not be free -- 
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/how-to-buy.html
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/ordnance-survey-business-portfolio-price-list.pdf

Comment: Well, you would need to decide what product suits your needs first. Then, read the link that I sent you - that is free, without doubt - this is part of the UK's public sector opening up (some) of their data to stimulate innovation. You can pay for enhanced versions, e.g. a greater level of coordinate accuracy for the postcode database, and more metadata per point.

Comment: -- alright in that ordnance survey - which option would give the postcode lookup? os-open-names-api.html?

Comment: I am struggling to get connected to that Ordnance survey --

Comment: They are updating the documentation - I've managed to gain access -

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps doesn't provide this function, as far as I am aware, however The Map It API from MySociety has a few "related areas" endpoints -

http://mapit.mysociety.org/#api-related_areas

So you can use their postcode to area lookup:-

http://mapit.mysociety.org/postcode/NW1%208AH.html

Note you will need to use a full postcode rather than just the District.

Then pass that area ID (2505 for Camden Borough Council) to the related area endpoint.

http://mapit.mysociety.org/area/2505/touches.html

Comment: @halfer - what about this service?

Comment: this shows promise -- looking into it -- isn't there quite a limitation on usage though - 1 call a sec

Comment: Well it's not free (unless you are a charity) however it's a useful service, you can always cache the second step (area ID) to reduce API calls too - http://mapit.mysociety.org/licensing